# How do I use Marketo REST API with Postman?

Tags: rest, postman, marketo

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to properly use the Marketo REST API using Postman for testing purpose.

So far I can Authenticate and get my access_token,

but when I try to create a folder... (properly authenticated)

**endpoint**: `[POST] /rest/asset/v1/folders.json`

**body**:

```json
{
  "description": "Test Folder",
  "name": "Test",
  "parent": {
    "id": 1,
    "type": "Folder"
  }
}
```

I get:

```json
{
    "success": false,
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "name cannot be null.",
            "code": "701"
        },
        {
            "message": "parent cannot be null",
            "code": "701"
        }
    ],
    "requestId": "408a#1720c00a893",
    "warnings": []
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [an example](https://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/assets/folders/#crayon-5f7c85af1e87d879852507) in the Marketo API documentation

Create/Update folder request should be an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` not `application/json`

So in Postman, you have to post a form with three parameters:

```
parent={"id":416,"type":"Folder"}
name=Test 10 - deverly
description=This is a test
```

For the `parent` parameter you should specify a specific json-like text, which is a usual format for `folderId`

[image]

For generic folders (not programs) you can provide just integer id, without JSON structure, this is not recommended but can be used for manual API tests